# Fuse-box server error, cannot get /path/to/url

Tags: reactjs, server, react-router, build-system

I'm using fuse-box with react and react-router, the problem is that with localhost:4444 it's working.. while with any other url like localhost:4444/landing or localhost:4444/signin, the browser show this error: Cannot GET /landing ...
any solution ?

Comment: Are you navigating to those other routes directly (i.e. entering them into the browser's URL bar)? Or are you navigating to them programatically (i.e. pushing the route into the browser history using react router)?

Comment: I am directly... actually I solved it by using HashRouter, buts still looking for solving it without HashRouter.. @Jayce444

Comment: Ok so the issue you're facing is client side vs server side routing. Programmatically navigating to a route and directly navigating to one aren't the same. There's plenty of stack overflows posts about this and other resources about it, just do a google search for "react router client vs server side routing" and do some research. Here's a post I answered earlier about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030285/react-router-v4-page-refresh-not-working/45030808#45030808