# react router : client side routing vs server side routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am playing with react router. I have created a simple app using it.

https://react-04-router.herokuapp.com/

If one click on aboutus or contactus, url is changing and new content is being shown. Everything is working perfectly fine till this point.

But if I refresh on the new link https://react-04-router.herokuapp.com/aboutus. it shows error page as "Not Found".

I have **not** configured /aboutus route at the server side and I guess this is the reason "Not found" error is coming but this makes me wonder following

1. If client side routing can not support on refresh, wouldn't it not impact user experience ?
2. To avoid impact on user experience if I decide to go with server side, I know i would lose faster response of client side routing, other than this, is there anything that I might miss out if I do not use client side routing.

Here is my router file code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import AboutUs from '../presentation/AboutUs';
import ContactUs from '../presentation/ContactUs';
import Home from '../presentation/Home';
import Navbar from '../presentation/Navbar';

class MainLayout extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <div >
          <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/aboutus' component={AboutUs}/>
            <Route path='/contactus' component={ContactUs}/>
          </Switch>              
        </div>       
      )
  }
}

export default MainLayout
```

And here is app.js file which renders

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from './presentation/Header';
import Footer from './presentation/Footer';
import MainLayout from './layout/MainLayout'

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Header />
                    <MainLayout/>
                <Footer />
            </div>
            )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: need to see how you're implementing `react-router`. Please include some code

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez Thanks for your response. I have added router code. Please let me know if any further code is needed.

Comment: You don't have to handle every specific route in the backend, but you need a catch all so that if they send a request to the server for a route that isn't specifically defined, you can just send the index.html back and let the front end router take them to their desired page. Have a look at my answer on this question for more details and a code fix example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030285/react-router-v4-page-refresh-not-working/45030808#45030808

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HashRouter in that case, see [Hash Router here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)

Comment: But as per best of my knowledge hash router is for static pages and not for dynamic content